# Можно ли запустить стандартный Test Runner, когда я запускаю unit тесты из Maven?

Tags: maven, юнит-тесты, java, junit, intellij-idea

Заранее извиняюсь, что картинки прикладываю в виде ссылок - моя репутация не дает возможности из загружать (<50).

Ситуация такая:

Когда я конфигурирую обычные тесты результат выдается в очень понятной, красивой и функциональной вкладке:

[image]

Когда я делаю билд через maven, то результат такой:

[image]

Придумал делать так, в основном build  конфиге (запуск стандартного junit плагина, запуск сборки мавеном):

[image]

И получается так, что в самом начале я получаю информацию из стандартного тест раннера, и все хорошо, а потом идет билд или деплой мавеном.

Вроде, меня все устраивает, но мне кажется, что можно сделать все более "правильно", т.е. запускать только сборку через Maven, изменив его раннер на тот, который нужен мне. Но как это сделать, я не нашел (и можно ли это сделать?).

Есть идеи?

Comment: @Wial, изображения можно отображать с помощью стандартного синтаксиса markdown (`![](путь к изображению)`)

Comment: Спасибо! Только теперь вторая и третья картинки не отображаются.

Comment: @Wial, это вопросы к хочтеру картинок, вчера были на месте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Правильного" решения здесь нет, ибо maven, условно говорю, запускается извне IDEA. Однако, если забить на то, что IDEA иногда не идеально поддерживает maven, то можно добавить к запуску maven-инструкции ключик '-Dmaven.test.skip=true' или в pom.xml добавить:

```
....
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```